# Shiny App name in browser tab not correct

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, tabs

The name of My Shiny app on the web tab (be it chrome or edge) is not appearing correctly. This started after I used this piece of code to change the colour of the title. The following is the way I've changed the name of the title.

```
PlayerFinishingOverview <- div("Player Finishing Overview", style = "color:#D81B60")
```

"PlayerFinishingOverview" is set within the titlePanel() within the fluidPage() fuction for the UI. This is how the name appears on the browser. [image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your `ui.R`

Comment: @PorkChop here is the link to my ui.R https://github.com/harshkrishna17/Miscellaneous-R/blob/main/ui.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `titlePanel` function for `windowTitle` it simply gets `h2` of the whatever it is you have your title named: I suggest you simply add the name for that too:

```
PlayerFinishingOverview <- div("Player Finishing Overview", style = "color:#D81B60")
PlayerFinishingOverviewWindow <- "Player Finishing Overview"
```

---

```
titlePanel(PlayerFinishingOverview,windowTitle = PlayerFinishingOverviewWindow)
```